# Modify next element in array during foreach() loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How can I modify the next element in a foreach() loop, during the loop? I think it has something to do with talking to the variable by reference but I'm not sure how. i.e.:

```
$arr = array( array('color' => 'red',    'type' => 'apple'),
              array('color' => 'yellow', 'type' => 'banana'),
              array('color' => 'purple', 'type' => 'grape')
            );

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
   echo "<br> The ".$v['type'].' fruit is '.$v['color'];

   // change the color of the next fruit?
   if($v['type'] == 'apple') { $arr[$k+1]['color'] = 'green'; }
}
```

I'd like this to tell me the banana is green, but it stubbornly sticks to the banana being yellow...

(UPDATE: fixed a stupid logic error in my original question. The answer marked below is correct.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

foreach loops through an array by taking a copy of the array and not by reference. You need to loop through the array by reference using the ampersand `&` on the array value.

```
foreach($arr as $k => &$v) {
   echo "<br> The ".$v['type'].' fruit is '.$v['color'];

   // change the color of the next fruit?
   if($v['type'] == 'banana') { $arr[$k+1]['color'] = 'green'; }
}
```

Comment: That's only one part of the solution (but nevertheless very important one). When `$v['type'] == 'banana'` is true, the next fruit which is modified is `grape`. If the banana should be green it must be `$v['type'] == 'apple'`.

Comment: I misread, I assumed when the original poster was refering to the next element he meant to change the color of the grape to green.

Comment: Well, I don't know. Using the reference solves the programming error. But he also stated *I'd like this to tell me the banana is green*, in which case he also has a logic error. But your answer should get him to the right track.

Comment: Oops, my bad on the logic (I wrote that script quickly here on StackOverflow without actually testing it)... but you understood what I was after and your answer is working for me, so... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$k=array_keys($yourarray);
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof ($k); $i++) {
       if($yourarray[$k[$i]] == "something") {
           $yourarray[$k[$i+1]] = "something else"; 
       }
    }
}
```

sorry formatting is all wonky as i am replying from a phone...

Answer (score -1):

The counter has to remain the same

```
$arr = array( array('color' => 'red',    'type' => 'apple'),
          array('color' => 'yellow', 'type' => 'banana'),
          array('color' => 'purple', 'type' => 'grape')
        );

foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
  echo "<br> The ".$v['type'].' fruit is '.$v['color'];

  // change the color of the next fruit?
  if($v['type'] == 'banana') { $arr[$k]['color'] = 'green'; }

  // now echo the new color from the original array 
   echo "<br> The ".$arr[$k]['type'].' fruit is now '.$arr[$k]['color'];
}
```